# Error does not occur when arbitrary classname is used with instanceof in PHP

Tags: php, instanceof

In the following code, using any **arbitrary** classname (*ABCDException*) with `instanceof` does not occur any fatal error.

```
<?php

function fn($x)
{
    if ($x === 0) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('cannot be zero');
    }
}

try {
    fn(0);
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    if ($ex instanceof ABCDException) {
        echo 'instance of ABCDException';
    }
}
```

In the page http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php, it has specified:

> There are a few pitfalls to be aware of. Before PHP version 5.1.0,
>   instanceof would call __autoload() if the class name did not exist. In
>   addition, if the class was not loaded, a fatal error would occur.

but it is still not clear why the occurring of fatal error was removed.

I want to know why error does not occur in this case.

Comment: Well if `ABCDException` hasn't already been loaded, then $ex cannot conceivably be an instance of that class (otherwise it would have been loaded when the exception was thrown), so is there any point in calling the autoloader... it can be treated as false without the overhead of trying to load the class

Comment: So simply we can say, PHP interpreter knows all the loaded classes from which existing objects has been created and it is unnecessary to try to load the class because an object cannot be of type which PHP has not loaded yet.

Comment: That pretty much sums it up

Comment: Doesn't this leads to bug as developer may assume the class in `instanceof`  is available and no error has been thrown, so the code is good. This may occur in case like when mistyped class: `InvalidArgmentException` instead of `InvalidArgumentException`.

Comment: That's a trade off between the overhead of loading the class (and potentially triggering a fatal error that would terminate the script in a "dirty" fashion); and the developers understanding/diligence.... but preventing a potential fatal error isn't normally considered to be a bug

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not need to know about the implementation details of `ABCDException` to figure out whether `$ex` is an `instanceof` it. All it needs to do is check if the object itself is an instance of a class of that name, or whether the object's class inherits from any parent of that name or whether any of those implement any interface of that name. Whether that name is actually defined as a class or interface is rather irrelevant for this purpose, as the implementation details would not change anything about the outcome.

I suppose the PHP developers stopped trying to load the actual class, as that just unnecessarily incurs a performance penalty.